# How to fill input field value from javascript id value?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty in getting value from javascript id to the input field. I tried all the answers available on the platform but not worked. while I am getting the value of id="price_div" properly but not in input filed just where id is named. mean id="price_div" has a value when i apply it as like  i got value here . but when i use  i don't get value in value filed

```
    <div class="title-calc">Approx. price</div>
  <div class="price-total" id="price_div">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value=""> //Here i want to add price div value
    <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"></span>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("price_div").children[0].value=price

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inaccurate retrieval of values from an input fields using javascript referenced by inputs class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338073/inaccurate-retrieval-of-values-from-an-input-fields-using-javascript-referenced)

Comment: mean id="price_div" has a value when i apply it as like <span id id="price_div"></span> i got value here . but when i use <input type=text value="" id="price_div"> i don't get value in value filed

Answer (score 1):

as i understood, you get the value but you can't put this value as the input value. the solution is here, suppose your value is x:

```
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = x;
```

Comment: i want to get value automatically that is loaded by id="price_div" not my own

Comment: is the value appended to the span with className of "price"?

Comment: mean id="price_div" has a value when i apply it as like <span id id="price_div"></span> i got value here . but when i use <input type=text value="" id="price_div"> i don't get value in value filed

Comment: Sorry but your question is Unclear cause we do not have a value directly to the "price_div" element and you could not describe what you want to do with this opacue value exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your input field and then append value through JavaScript

```
<div class="title-calc">Approx. price</div>
   <div class="price-total" id="price_div">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" id="name" value="">
          <span class="currency">$</span><span class="price"></span>

<script>
var input_value = document.getElementById("price_div").value 
document.getElementById("name").value = input_value
</script>
```

Comment: i want to get value automatically that is loaded by id="price_div" not my own

Comment: what do you mean by automatically ? are you using any backend server ?

Comment: mean id="price_div" has a value when i apply it as like <span id id="price_div"></span> i got value here . but when i use <input type=text value="" id="price_div"> i don't get value in value filed

Comment: getting <input type="hidden" name="price" id="name" value="undefined">

Comment: @cryptohacks can you tell me how you will give value to your div with `id="price_div"`

Comment: its loading from javascript files with function of calculator

Answer (score 0):

div has no value ... so to reach input use

```
var INP = document.getElementById("price_div").firstChild
```

or

```
var INP =document.querySelectorAll("#price_div [name=price]")[0]
```

then `INP.value='smth'`

use input which is hidden to show   a value in span

```
var SPAN = INP.parent.lastChild; 
INP.addEventListener('change',function(ev){SPAN.innerHTML=INP.value;});
```

Comment: mean id="price_div" has a value when i apply it as like <span id id="price_div"></span> i got value here . but when i use <input type=text value="" id="price_div"> i don't get value in value filed

Comment: yes you got my point . but i am too beginers in js please can you modify it with my code . you are right its gets only value when its span class=price

Answer (score 0):

this solved my error 
var INP = document.getElementByClasses("span").firstChild